# How to stop streaming mp3 file in UIWebview

Tags: ios

I want to stop streaming mp3 file in UIWebview without reload page.

So I don't want reload page to stop. It's not best way. Does anyone suggest an idea for me ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply load blank page to stop streaming mp3 file.

Like this :

```
[self.yrwebContent loadRequest:NSURLRequestFromString(@"about:blank")];
```

UPDATE: Another solution, play sound using [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) instead

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.sFilePath];
NSData *yrSound = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
AVAudioPlayer *SoundPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:yrSound  error:NULL];
SoundPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
[SoundPlayer play];
```

Then, you stop it by using :

```
[SoundPlayer stop];
```

Comment: Thank. i fixed it. 
 [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];

Comment: Did it solve your problem as well , stop streaming mp3 file ?

Comment: Can i have a question ? When i tried your code, it will appear a new tab "about:blank"". it works fine, the sound was stop, but i don't want to show a new tab. I want to keep current tab, but we still stop streaming mp3. Can you suggest for me an another idea ?

Comment: Maybe you can play the sound using  AVAudioPlayer instead. I will edit the answer for you. wait a sec.

Comment: Thank so much ! let me try !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27318/discussion-between-nguyen-duc-and-thanakron-tandavas)